# Server install stuck with error: Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nginx

Trying to get Ruby 2.0.0 running on CentOS 6.5 with nginx and Passenger. So far, having no luck due to the error: http://prntscr.com/3egoca

This is the process I used for installing the PostgreSQL server for use with Ruby:

```
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

# In both [base] and [updates] sections I added the following line to the file above:
# exclude=postgresql*

sudo rpm -Uvh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install postgresql93 postgresql93-devel postgresql93-server postgresql93-libs postgresql93-contrib
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 initdb
sudo service postgresql-9.3 start
sudo chkconfig --levels 235 postgresql-9.3 on

# At the bottom of this file I changed authentication method to md5:
sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
sudo service postgresql-9.3 restart
```

So far so good and PostgreSQL works as expected when tested, but then this is where it fails:

```
bundle install
```

This gives me the error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

So I followed that advice and tried installing the PG gem separately like so:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config
```

When I try that, I get this output:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.17.1
invalid options: -f fivefish
(invalid options are ignored)
Parsing documentation for pg-0.17.1
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ../../extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/pg-0.17.1/pg_ext.so, skipping
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/pg_ext.so, skipping
1 gem installed
```

Despite saying it successfully installed I still get the Passenger error I posted a screenshot of and I still can't get `bundle install` to run successfully.

BTW, I am SSH'd in as user 'deploy' which is what nginx is also set as the user in the nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks!!! In my case with MacOs and Postgree.app the path was "Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"